# Trying to copy JAR file from local machine to linux server

Tags: linux, windows, jar, server

I am trying to copy a jar file from my local machine to linux(centos) server, but I am getting an error.

This is my command:

```
pscp Watch.jar dev@10.10.40.74:/home/dev/Documents
```

Watch.jar is the name of my jar and dev is my user on my server. I am trying to copy this file to a particular location(home/dev/Documents)

The error I got is:

```
Watch.jar: Network Error occurred
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVBIj.png

And when I run `java -jar Watch.jar` on my linux server, it says

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt file.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming? Also, why on earth would you expect your jar to work after a network error?

Comment: Retry the scp and if it succeeds without error, execute the jar